# django fails to load updated CSS

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

Django in my project its loading all the css characteristics even if i have deleted them. All the modifications in the html can be reflected but in css modifications doesn't shows up.
Its like django is not loading the updated elements in the CSS file. Any clue how can i fix it ?

My settings.py file :-

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '^&kq%o*0_&to!+l51tf@tnox6448q0&y7_arz0-uyp8txz5zb4'
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'ckeditor',
'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
"default": {
    "removePlugins": "stylesheetparser",
}
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'MyBlog.urls'

TEMPLATES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
)

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'MyBlog.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT ='D:/projects/PyCharm projects/MyBlog/blog/media/'
MEDIA_URL ='/blog/media/'

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
},
{
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
},
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Try Debug=False it will help i think. After css loaded make debug True.

Comment: probably browser cache

Comment: try to refresh the page in your browser using ctrl+f5

Comment: i have tried but nothing changed @AbdulMajeed

Comment: if its a browser cache problem how can i correct it  ? @devxplorer